# Cancel all subscriptions in a useEffect cleanup function created by Context.Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

Each time when `onClick` executes I received a warning message about memory leak. How component can be can unsubscribed from the *Context.Consumer* in my functional component with `useEffect` hook?

I did not find a way how to unsubscribe from the AppContext. `AppContext.unsubsribe()` did not work.

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {AppContext} from "../context/AppContext";

const LoginPage = (props) => {

    const [name, setName] = useContext(AppContext);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const onClick = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        axios.post('/get-name')
            .then(resp => {
                setName(resp);
                setIsLoading(false);
                props.history.push('/');
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}></button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(LoginPage);
```

Error message in the browser console:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in a useEffect cleanup function.
>       in UserPage (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(UserPage))
>       in withRouter(LoginPage) (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Route (created by UserRoute)

Comment: Is the issue really with the AppContext?  I think the issue is that you're doing `setIsLoading` after the component is unmounted.

Comment: How should I execute cleanup for the `setIsLoading` method and `isLoading` property?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that axios is returning a promise, so when the component is mounted, it executes `axios.post(...)` on click. When it THEN unmounts (while the promise could still be "unfinished"), the `setState` of its `finally` will execute AFTER the component unmounted.

You can use an easy check if the component is mounted:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {AppContext} from "../context/AppContext";

const LoginPage = (props) => {

    const [name, setName] = useContext(AppContext);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const isMounted = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      // executed when component mounted
      isMounted.current = true;
      return () => {
        // executed when unmount
        isMounted.current = false;
      }
    }, []);

    const onClick = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        axios.post('/get-name')
            .then(resp => {
                setName(resp);
                setIsLoading(false);
                props.history.push('/');
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => {
               if (isMounted.current) {
                 setIsLoading(false)
               }
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}></button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(LoginPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states, in your `UserPage` component you need to perform a cleanup on `useEffect` to avoid memory leaks.

Refer to [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#recap) how to require cleanup after an effect.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });
```

Comment: I have seen this example in the documentation. For me not clear which exactly methods should be executed in my case. I do not have subscription to external component that can provide `unsubscribe` method like `ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(...)`

Comment: Add your `UserPage`, even better just make a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bennet Dams I could solve my issue, this is my code following his example

```js
  const isMounted = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    fetchRequestsData();
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  async function fetchRequestsData() {
  
  //My previous code which led to the warning
    /* const { data } = await axios({
      url: '../api/random/my-requests',
      method: 'get',
    });
    setSuspendedRequests(data.suspended); */

    let data;
    axios
      .get('../api/random/my-requests')
      .then((resp) => {
        data = resp.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setSuspendedRequests(data.suspended);
        }
      });
  }
```