# change route during axios causes memory leak in useEffect Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This error happens when I click on a tab and the data table is loading(during an axios call), and before the load is completed (axios returns the data) I click on a link that takes me to another Route within the same website.

Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (reloadTable) {
    setReloadTable(false); // Forces this useEffect to be called once
  } else {
    let dataSelected = [];
    const options = {
      keyName: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_NAME,
      keyValue: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_VALUE
    }
    if(tab === "Instructors"){
      setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(true);
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Instructors/GetAllInstructors`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.instructors.map(instructorData => {
            return {id: instructorData.id, name: instructorData.name, assistants: instructorData.assistants, students: instructorData.students, hours: instructorData.hours, classes: instructorData.classes};
          });
          setTableInstructorData(dataSelected);
          setInstructorDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      );
    }
    if(tab === "Assistants"){
      setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(true);
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Assistants/GetAllAssistants`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.assistants.map(assistantData => {
            return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, hours: assistantData.hours};
          });
          setTableAssistantsData(dataSelected);
          setAssistantsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      );
    }
    if(tab === "Students"){
      setIsLoadingStudentsTable(true);
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Students/GetAllStudents`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.students.map(studentData => {
            return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, books: assistantData.books, classes: assistantData.classes};
          });
          setTableStudentsData(dataSelected);
          setStudentsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
        }
      );
    }
  }
}, [tab, reloadTable]);
```

Here is the error I'm seeing:

[image]

I tried looking up the "useEffect cleanup function" as the error suggested, but couldn't find anything useful to solve the issue with this code. Anyone have any ideas?

---

**Edit: Attempting useRef()**

After finding one solution here > [Cancel all subscriptions in a useEffect cleanup function created by Context.Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584107/cancel-all-subscriptions-in-a-useeffect-cleanup-function-created-by-context-cons)

I tried implementing it with this code...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const isMounted = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  if (reloadTable) {
    setReloadTable(false); // Forces this useEffect to be called once
  } else {
    let dataSelected = [];
    const options = {
      keyName: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_NAME,
      keyValue: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_VALUE
    }
    if(tab === "instructors"){
      setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Instructors/GetAllInstructors`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.instructors.map(instructorData => {
            return {id: instructorData.id, name: instructorData.name, assistants: instructorData.assistants, students: instructorData.students, hours: instructorData.hours, classes: instructorData.classes};
          });
          setTableInstructorData(dataSelected);
          setInstructorDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
        }
      });
    }
    if(tab === "assistants"){
      setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Assistants/GetAllAssistants`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.assistants.map(assistantData => {
            return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, hours: assistantData.hours};
          });
          setTableAssistantsData(dataSelected);
          setAssistantsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
        }
      });
    }
    if(tab === "students"){
      setIsLoadingStudentsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Students/GetAllStudents`, options)
      .then(data => {
          dataSelected = data.data.students.map(studentData => {
            return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, books: assistantData.books, classes: assistantData.classes};
          });
          setTableStudentsData(dataSelected);
          setStudentsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
          setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
          setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
          setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
          setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      ).finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}, [tab, reloadTable]);
```

But the error still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ref that indicates if the component is unmounted before doing all the state updates. You then set it to `true` when the component unmounts:

```
const mounted = useRef(true);

// this will set mounted to false when unmounting...
useEffect(() => () => { mounted.current = false; }, []);

useEffect(() => {
   axios.get(/**/).then(data => {
     if (mounted.current) {
       // do the state updates
     }
   })
}, [/* some requirements*/]);
```

Or without a ref entirely:

```
useEffect(() => {

   let mounted = true;

   axios.get(/**/).then(data => {
     if (mounted) {
       // do the state updates
     }
   })

   return () => mounted = false;
}, [/* some requirements*/]);
```

The difference is that in that case the state updates will also be canceled if any of the dependencies of your effect change. This may arguably even be the better solution. But this is not a problem because another request will also be enqueued.

Comment: This definitely works, the only thing I had to add was before the axios, setting `mounted.current = true` and at the end of the if statement after the promise return set `mounted.current = false`. If I didn't do these two things, it sets the loading permanently true so the data never populates.

Comment: @FiddleFreak It should already be set to `true` by passing the initial value `useRef(true)`. Did you use two separate `useEffect`s? You can also do it without a ref entirely. I updated my answer with that. Please also check this out.

Comment: this happens during tab switching, because once an axios call happens the 2nd time the value is false and so everything within the if statement never gets executed.

Comment: @FiddleFreak But that actually shouldn't be possible as it is only set to `false` on unmounting (not after the request, thus the two separate `useEffect`s) and if the component mounts again it will create a new ref that is `true` again. But the solution without a ref might anyways be better.

Comment: when switching between tabs, the component doesn't unmount. It's only when switching between routes the component unmounts. Clicking a new tab causes it to load data for that table (instructors/assistants/students). So once data is loaded for one tab/table, it cannot be loaded for another tab/table unless isMounted is set to true before making the axios call. Please refer to my reference solution code answer.

Comment: FYI, I definitely think the non-ref solution is definitely better. I was experiencing tab data loading issues between switching tabs before the data loaded with the `useRef()` solution. This saved me loads of trial and error boolean flag setting theories with `useEffect()` lifecycle's management.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructor callback of useEffect along with a flag with useState.

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)

// Inside your useEffect
useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);

    //Inside your axios call
    axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Instructors/GetAllInstructors`, options)
        .then(data => {
            if (isMounted) {
              ...
              ...
     }
   });
   // destructor callback
   return () => {
     setIsMounted(false);
   }
});
```

Comment: This also seems like a clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to render anything after the component is unmounted then you can use this code sample to achieve that.

I have created _IsMounted variable and set it to false. When useEffect is called that means component are mounted, so it set _IsMounted to true.

When the component are unmounted from screen the react calls return method from useEffect and it set _IsMounted to false. So when you try to update state when there is no component mounted, it will not leads to crash.

This will not cancel subscription or async code but they will not effect the application or leads to any error.

```
let IS_MOUNTED = false; // define in global scope

useEffect(() => {

  IS_MOUNTED = true;
   
  thisIsFuntion();

  return (() => {
    IS_MOUNTED = false;
  })

},[])


const thisIsFuntion = () => {
   
   if(IS_MOUNTED)
   {
      // Update your state only if compoment is mounted
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, here is the solution code...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const isMounted = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => () => { isMounted.current = false; }, []);
useEffect(() => {
  if (reloadTable) {
    setReloadTable(false); // Forces this useEffect to be called once
  } else {
    let dataSelected = [];
    const options = {
      keyName: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_NAME,
      keyValue: process.env.REACT_APP_KEY_VALUE
    }
    if(tab === "instructors"){
      setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Instructors/GetAllInstructors`, options)
      .then(data => {
          if(isMounted.current){
            dataSelected = data.data.instructors.map(instructorData => {
                return {id: instructorData.id, name: instructorData.name, assistants: instructorData.assistants, students: instructorData.students, hours: instructorData.hours, classes: instructorData.classes};
            });
            setTableInstructorData(dataSelected);
            setInstructorDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
            setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
            setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
            setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
            setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
            setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
            setSearchTerm("");
            isMounted.current = false;
          }
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingInstructorsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      );
    }
    if(tab === "assistants"){
      setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Assistants/GetAllAssistants`, options)
      .then(data => {
          if(isMounted.current){
            dataSelected = data.data.assistants.map(assistantData => {
              return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, hours: assistantData.hours};
            });
            setTableAssistantsData(dataSelected);
            setAssistantsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
            setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
            setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
            setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
            setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
            setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
            setSearchTerm("");
            isMounted.current = false;
          }
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingAssistantsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      );
    }
    if(tab === "students"){
      setIsLoadingStudentsTable(true);
      isMounted.current = true;
      axios.post(`https://example.com/school/api/Students/GetAllStudents`, options)
      .then(data => {
          if(isMounted.current){
            dataSelected = data.data.students.map(studentData => {
              return {id: assistantData.id, name: assistantData.name, books: assistantData.books, classes: assistantData.classes};
            });
            setTableStudentsData(dataSelected);
            setStudentsDisplayTableData(dataSelected);
            setListOfBooks(data.data.books);
            setListOfClasses(data.data.classes);
            setListOfcurriculums(data.data.datacurriculums);
            setListOfMeetings(data.data.);
            setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
            setSearchTerm("");
            isMounted.current = false;
          }
        }
      ).catch(err => {
          console.log('error:', err);
          setIsLoadingStudentsTable(false);
          setSearchTerm("");
          isMounted.current = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
}, [tab, reloadTable]);
```